# How to specify font size less than 10pt (or more than 12pt)?

Tags: fontsize

I'm trying to make a document that has a very small font throughout, I tried this:

```
\documentclass[0.5mm, a4paper]{article}
\documentclass[7pt, a4paper]{article}
```

But it doesn't seem that they allow me to go anything below 10pt.

This hack make it work, but not for the section headers:

```
\fontsize{4mm}{5mm}\selectfont
```

Does anyone know any better ways to do this?

Comment: I've got to say, this is one of the arcane areas of latex that really bugs me. If you specify something, it should work, or give you an error explaining why. Not just not work and then you have to really sort it out.

Comment: @AaronHall I asked this question 4 years ago when I was still writing my thesis, I'm very surprised that until now a lot of people still upvote and comment on this very simple question.

Comment: To be fair, nowadays LaTeX give the "**LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s)**" message, although it's "just" a warning not an error. (so, get the habit to not ignore warning messages)

Comment: Related question, [fontsize - How to specify an arbitrary (possibly non-integer) font size in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47517/how-to-specify-an-arbitrary-possibly-non-integer-font-size-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

- [extsizes](http://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) classes offer a base font size between 8 and 20 pt, you may choose the `extarticle` class
- [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes support freely customizable base font sizes and you may specify them by any TeX length unit like pt, bp or mm, so you might use scrartcl.

I recommend to use a KOMA-Script class.

Comment: the `memoir` class also has a variety of document font sizes available.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use KOMA-script?

Comment: @evaristegd I chat a lot in the [LaTeX.org forum](https://latex.org/forum/), we could talk there about further stuff. Here it's straight question & answer.

Comment: I texmaker even after using extarticle, it is allowing up to 14pt size, how to go beyond that?

Answer (score 53):

Instead of switching to a `KOMA-Script` *class*, you may also use the `scrextend` package (part of [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)) and its `\changefontsizes` macro. It features an optional argument to change `\baselineskip` (the default is 1.2 * fontsize). For details see section 3.5 of the [`KOMA-Script` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) (the relevant content also applies to `scrextend`, as mentioned in section 9.5 of the manual). *EDIT: Make sure to use a scalable font (e.g. Latin Modern instead of Computer Modern).*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes[20pt]{16pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Meanwhile the preferred way seems to consist in giving the fontsize as package option `\usepackage[fontsize=16pt]{scrextend}`. The command `\changefontsizes` is now hardly documented: no mention of the optional argument anymore.

Comment: Instead of using `\changefontsizes` one could (and should) rather use `\KOMAoption{fontsize}{16pt}` (which is the same as the package option), see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108732/

Answer (score 22):

It is a semantically better practice to define a new font size which is a size less than `tiny`, rather than use `\fontsize`, by using:

```
\makeatletter
  \newcommand\tinyv{\@setfontsize\tinyv{4pt}{6}}
\makeatother
```

I called, it `tinyv` (v being the size in roman numerals), but you can call it anything you wish.

You can also change any of the others this way, by using `renewcommand`. You can do this in the class file you are using, in which case you do not need the apocryphal `\makeatletter` and `makeatother`.

```
\renewcommand\scriptsize{@setfontsize\scriptsize{5}{7}}
```

Comment: How are `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` apocryphal?

Comment: @TH people new to TeX/LaTeX - after they get used to the idea of macro names such as @var@able@, get another surprise with `makeatletter` etc. Unless you know about catcodes the semantics of `makeatletter` and especially `makeatother` are very esoteric and hence apocryphal! There are other mysteries too like `futurelet`!.

Comment: @TH.: I think Yiannis means "cryptic". Then I'd agree. (@Yiannis: correct?)

Comment: @Hendrik Partly:) written in the sense ... The word "apocryphal" (ἀπόκρυφος) was first applied, in a positive sense, to writings which were kept secret because they were the vehicles of esoteric knowledge... (source: wikipedia). On top we got the Book! In greek the meaning is something between cryptic, esoteric, of high value but hidden!

Comment: @Yiannis: Interesting; I didn't know this meaning of apocryphal. The problem is that most of us don't know Greek that well (I learned Ancient Greek at school, but that's some time ago). In English, apocryphal things have the tendency to be just not true.

Comment: @Hendrik Yes, an apocryphal story is not such a good thing! The `makeatletter` is such a surprise to newcomers, especially as you  get an error if you miss it, telling you that the `spacefactor is not allowed in vertical mode'.

Comment: @Yiannis: yes, in current English usage *apocryphal* means roughly “rumoured, but non-existent”.  Other good words for `\makeat`(`letter`|`other`) could be *arcane*, *occult*, *mystical*.  They were certainly mystical incantations to me for a while — I knew I had to say them as part of certain rituals, but I had only the vaguest idea of why.

Comment: @Yiannis: will this cause other font-size commands to scale accordingly? Also, you said you named it \tinyv because that is the font size in roman numerals, but you have specified: `\makeatletter \newcommand\tinyv{\@setfontsize\tinyv{4pt}{6}} \makeatother`  **Why does** `{4pt}{6}` set the font to 5pt?

Comment: @RaxAdaam `tiny` works like `\small` or `\large`. The reason that LateX substitutes a 5pt is that it cannot find a 4pt font (with default fonts), if you check the logs you will see LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <4> not available
(Font)   size <5> substituted on input line 9.

Comment: @Yiannis, so this is not equivalent to setting the document's working or reference font size, just to set a specific font size. I'd like to set the font size for the document lower, but have things like \tiny \footnotesize etc. scale accordingly. Also, if it will just set it to 5pt, why write 4pt?

Answer (score 17):

Another option is to use the [`extsizes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) package. Although it doesn't provide a 16 point font, 14 and 17 point options are available:

```
\documentclass[17pt]{extreport}
```

I would also like to cite the `extsizes` documentation:

> Don't use `extsizes` just because you think it's cool, or because you
>   think the font looks too small on the screen. You should have a clear
>   reason why 10, 11 or 12 pt text is not suitable for you.

Comment: there is a good reason, its in the specs.

Answer (score 13):

Use a class which supports more fontsizes. E.g. one of the KOMA-classes:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=16pt]{scrreprt}
```

Comment: I am using miktex, which package do I install for KOMA-classes?

Comment: @Rick_2047 If you have set MikTeX to install missing packages on the fly, simply compile a document with a KOMA-class, and it will be installed for you. If not, open the Package Manager and search for "koma", then you'll find it.

Comment: Both are strangely not working. It shows that dialog box that says it wants to install but never installs. And koma-class just doesn't show up in the package manager.

Comment: How long do you wait? It can take perhaps a few minutes, whil nothing appears to be happening. I just tried a search in the package manager of MikTeX (Portable), and searching for "koma" yielded two results, the first being "koma-script".

Comment: @Rick Which miktex version are you using? And to which repository are you trying to connect? Did you synchronize the repository (package manager, menu repositories)

Comment: i got it working. thanks. For some reason when I put koma in keywords field the package didn't show up

Answer (score 10):

Similar to what the KOMA-script classes provide, the `memoir` document class also offers `14pt` and `17pt` (but *not* 16pt) options for the basic font size of a document. The `memoir` class-related files should be installed automatically by most modern TeX distributions. If not, use your package manager -- tlmgr or MikTeX's own update program -- to install them.

You'd select these fontsize options with the commands

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
```

and

```
\documentclass[17pt,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
```

respectively. I suggest you include the option `extrafontsizes` when using the `17pt` size option. Doing so will ensure that commands that change relative font sizes -- such as `\Large`, `\huge`, and `\Huge` -- will produce reasonable-looking results. Specifically, the Latin Modern fonts in `T1` encoding will be loaded instead of the default Computer Modern fonts in `OT1` encoding.

Comment: I have been looking for something similar, I would like to use a memoir 13pt font size, is it possible?

Comment: @Adriano - According to the user guide of the memoir package, the following default font sizes (in points) are provided: 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 20, 25, 30, 36, 48, and 60. For each of these sizes, a file called `mem?.clo` exists, where `?` can be 9, 10, etc and `clo` stands for "class option". For new font sizes, e.g., `13pt`, you'd have to set up a file named `mem13.clo`, along the lines explained in the user guide. For the case of `13pt`, you could probably use `mem12.clo` and `mem14.clo` as templates and average the values used in those two files for the new file.