# How to change font size in the entire document?

Tags: fontsize

How should I change font size for the entire document? I want to design a presentation and fonts should be larger, all of them.

Comment: Uh, use the fontsize argument to the documentclass?

Comment: `12pt` is the maximum, as far as I know. I need bigger fonts, 16pt actually.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5339/1235). Is your question answered there?

Answer (score 7):

Not really an answer to your question. But there are special classes for presentations (which is what you want to do) that change fonts etc.

The most famous is probably [`beamer`](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/entries/beamer.html) but there are also some specifically for transparencies if you want that. Have a look at the [catalogue](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/bytopic.html#present).

Comment: Just FYI, the way beamer handles the problem is to make the document itself very small, so 12pt fonts look very big in full-screen mode. It works quite well, though.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. It does change the default to sans serif though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\begin{document}
  {\fontsize{40pt}{48pt}\selectfont 40pt,} 
  {\Huge It's Huge,} 
  {\fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont 30pt,} 
  {\tiny It's tiny,} 
  {\fontsize{3.5pt}{4.2pt}\selectfont 3.5pt,}
\end{document}
```

[source](https://latexhelp.com/latex-font-size-change/)