# How to change the font size of a document?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to specify font size less than 10pt in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-in-latex)

Sometimes when I want to review a draft I need larger fonts. Is there a package or a command that I can use to increase the font of the entire document?

Comment: Have a look at: [How to change font size in the entire document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7447/how-to-change-font-size-in-the-entire-document) and [How to specify font size less than 10pt in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-in-latex), even if it should be bigger.