# Poster and (very) bold math fonts

Tags: beamer, fonts, bold, posters

I've spent several hours to put some mathematical laws for powers and logarithm on a poster.

The output is too thin for reading it standing a few meters away, especially sitting in a classroom in the last row.

I have to use a bold font for math, but I don't find any solution.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer} % beamer 3.10: do NOT use option hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false} !
  \mode<presentation> {  
    \usetheme{default}   
  }
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
  %\usepackage{times}\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  % times is obsolete
  \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
  \boldmath
  \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a1,scale=2.4,debug]{beamerposter}                       % e.g. for DIN-A0 poster
  \title[]{Potenz- und Logarithmengesetze}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{} 
    \vfill
   \begin{block}{\Huge\hspace{2cm} Potenzgesetze}
\[\def\arraystretch{2}\begin{array}{rclp{5cm}} 
    a^m \cdot a^m & = &a^{m+n} &\\
\displaystyle \frac{a^m}{a^n} & =& a^{m-n} \\
    (a \cdot b)^m & =& a^m \cdot b^m \\
    \displaystyle \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^m & = & \displaystyle \frac{a^m}{b^m} \\
    \bigl( a^m \bigr)^n & =& a^{m \cdot n} \\
      \end{array}
        \]
\end{block}
\vfill 
\begin{block}{\Huge\hspace{2cm} Logarithmengesetze}
        \[ \def\arraystretch{2}\begin{array}{rcl}
        \ln(a \cdot b) & = &\ln(a) + \ln(b) \\
        \displaystyle \ln\left( \frac{a}{b} \right) & = &\ln(a) - \ln(b) \\
        \ln(a^b) & =& b \cdot \ln(a) \\
        \ln(e)   & = &1 \\
        \ln(1)   & = &0 \\
        \ln(e^x) & = &e^{\ln(x)} = x 
        \end{array}\]
\end{block}
    \vfill
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

That is one of my attemps. No luck.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6):

Why not increasing the size of the font in the `array`s?

Use for example `\large` before `\begin{array}` and adjust the spacing before it (I've used `\vspace*{-3cm}`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer} % beamer 3.10: do NOT use option hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false} !
  \mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{default}
  }
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
  %\usepackage{times}\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  % times is obsolete
  \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
  \boldmath
  \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a1,scale=2.4,debug]{beamerposter}                       % e.g. for DIN-A0 poster
  \title[]{Potenz- und Logarithmengesetze}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{}
    \vfill
   \begin{block}{\Huge\hspace{2cm} Potenzgesetze}\vspace*{-3cm}
\[\def\arraystretch{2}\large\begin{array}{rclp{5cm}}
    a^m \cdot a^m & = &a^{m+n} &\\
\displaystyle \frac{a^m}{a^n} & =& a^{m-n} \\
    (a \cdot b)^m & =& a^m \cdot b^m \\
    \displaystyle \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^m & = & \displaystyle \frac{a^m}{b^m} \\
    \bigl( a^m \bigr)^n & =& a^{m \cdot n} \\
      \end{array}
        \]
\end{block}
\vfill
\begin{block}{\Huge\hspace{2cm} Logarithmengesetze}\vspace*{-3cm}
        \[ \def\arraystretch{2}\large\begin{array}{rcl}
        \ln(a \cdot b) & = &\ln(a) + \ln(b) \\
        \displaystyle \ln\left( \frac{a}{b} \right) & = &\ln(a) - \ln(b) \\
        \ln(a^b) & =& b \cdot \ln(a) \\
        \ln(e)   & = &1 \\
        \ln(1)   & = &0 \\
        \ln(e^x) & = &e^{\ln(x)} = x
        \end{array}\]
\end{block}
    \vfill
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have a bold font in math mode? You could try the package bm and use it like `$\bm{\frac{1}{2}}$`. Other solutions: [How can I get bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols) ... you can btw change all fonts to bold using `\boldmath` (after begin document).

One thing is too make them bold. But you could also change the fontsize [How to change the font size of a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10619/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-a-document)