# How to set a small default font size with beamer?

Tags: beamer, fontsize

I use `beamer` class with  `newcent` package for the font. I set

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
```

at the top of my tex file. But I think the font is still too large.

In my beamer theme, I tried to set :

```
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{size=\small}
```

But it does not work and I think that it is not the correct way to do that.

How can I globally reduce the font size ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify font size less than 10pt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt)

Comment: The other question's accepted answer is about `extsizes` and `KOMA-Script` *classes*, but not about `scrextend`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to section 18.2.1 of the `beamer` manual, a default font size of 8pt is already *"way too small"*. `beamer` uses the [`extsizes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) packages for non-standard font sizes, and `extsizes` doesn't offer anything smaller than 8pt. If you really must fit more text on each frame, I suggest to enlarge `beamer`'s paper size from 128mm*96mm to, say, 140mm*105mm.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}

\geometry{paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=105mm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Another option is to load the `scrextend` package (part of `KOMA-Script`) which allows to choose arbitrary font sizes like 7.5pt -- be sure to use a vector font like Latin Modern.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes{7.5pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I prefer your first trick. I think it is easier to use it.

Comment: [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)

Comment: This works well for me. Then only issue is that "em" does not recognize the adjusted font size, so I need to change all specified spaces.

Comment: `scrextend` works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to change the size of the normal text, you could very well use the `\setbeamerfont{normal text}{size=\small}` macro from your question, you'll just have to also make beamer use it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{normal text}{size=\small}
\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont{normal text}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Why is the AtBeginDocument needed in this case?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Beamer does not use it automatically, one needs to nudge it a little bit.