# How do I increase the default font size of all slides in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, fontsize

I found in the question
[How to set a small default font size with beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56768/how-to-set-a-small-default-font-size-with-beamer)
that you can reduce the default font size in Beamer by writing

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
```

However, the answer to this question doesn't explain
how I can make the default font size bigger rather than smaller.

My questions are:

1. What is the default font size?
2. What other default font sizes are supported besides `8pt`?

**Note:**
I was able to find the answer to this question on my own,
but I am posting the question here
because I believe that the answer would be useful to others.

Comment: I take it you know that it is perfectly ok to answer your own question? So please add your answer.

Comment: For an overview see beamer user guide "18.2.1 Choosing a Font Size for Normal Text"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:**
I am grateful to
[samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter)
who pointed out that the information that I provided below
is also available in the beamer user guide
"18.2.1 Choosing a Font Size for Normal Text".

I was able to find that in the source code of
the [beamer.cls](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamer.cls)
file,
there are relevant lines:

```
\def\beamer@size{{size11.clo}}

\DeclareOptionBeamer{8pt}{\def\beamer@size{{size8.clo}}}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{9pt}{\def\beamer@size{{size9.clo}}}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{10pt}{\def\beamer@size{{size10.clo}}}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{11pt}{\def\beamer@size{{size11.clo}}}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{12pt}{\def\beamer@size{{size12.clo}}}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{14pt}{\def\beamer@size{{size14.clo}}}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{17pt}{\def\beamer@size{{size17.clo}}}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{20pt}{\def\beamer@size{{size20.clo}}}
```

These lines indicate that the default font size is `11pt`,
and that the options `Xpt` are available
for X in {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 20}. Furthermore `smaller` (same as `10pt`) and `bigger` (same as `12pt`) are available. All options besides `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt` require the `extsize` package to be installed.

#### MWE: 20pt

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
This is 20pt.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### MWE: 8pt

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
This is 8pt.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: These options are listed in the manual as well, see the comment by samcarter to your question.

Comment: And notice that some options are only available depending on other packages to be installed.

Comment: I added `smaller` and `bigger` as options. Hope that's ok with you.

Comment: how do I change the font size for a certain portion of text in a slide and maintain the initially set size everywhere else?