# How to set a non-standard font size in beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts

For example, `\documentclass[9.5pt]{beamer}`

Comment: Not so easy. Beamer has a lot of element each one with its font. If you look at the first page of http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf you can have an idea. You can also look at the file `beamerfontthemedefault.sty` somewhere in your distribution tree.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56768/how-to-set-a-small-default-font-size-with-beamer could help