# Changing font option in Latex document doesn't seem to change the font size

Tags: fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to specify font size less than 10pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt)

I use Texmaker for most of my LaTeX-ing but I'm running into some trouble trying to change the default font for the whole document.

From what I've read, changing the `??pt` in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

Should do the trick but it doesn't seem to work for my document.

Anything else I could try?

Comment: The predefined options for standard document classes are `10pt` (default), `11pt` or `12pt`. Do you need anything different?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "it doesn't seem to work." Do you receive any warnings in your `.log` file, or perhaps errors? Or do you need anything different from the font sizes @_GonzaloMedina mentioned?

Comment: I think I got this figured out.
Seems that I needed to change it to an extarticle in order to use larger font sizes with it.
Dumb mistake.