# Altering the position of bullet given by \item

Tags: tables, lists, vertical-alignment, itemize, resume

I am working on my resume and for that I am using one of the following construct:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,9pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}

\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.85}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\hoffset}{3pt}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.6in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7.488in}

\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{\vspace{-.12cm}\hspace{-5pt}
\begin{tabular*}{7.18in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{#1} &  #2 \\
    #3 & #4 \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-0.2cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize} 
\item
\ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}  
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The command `\ressubheading` helps me define a table in which I write my credentials. However, I need to itemize such tables and while doing so the bullet provided by `\item` hangs in the middle of the two rows. This is looking kind of odd. I would like the bullet to be in front of the first row i.e. say in front of "Name of Grad School" in the example given. Here is an image showing the problem:[image: example]

An ideas on what can be done ? Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than having the adjustments made by odd-valued or trial-and-error lengths, what about using regular paragraph entries:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{%
  \item\textbf{#1} \hfill #2\null\\
  #3 \hfill #4%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize} 
\ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}  
\ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}  
\ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}  
\ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}  
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Note that the standard document classes do not support `9pt` font. Also, document layout changes is best set using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

Finally, you could (should) consider some resume-dedicated packages like [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv). Search for questions tagged [moderncv](/questions/tagged/moderncv).

Comment: Werner: Thanks for the comments ! This worked out quite well for me. I didn't know that 9pt font is not supported. So what font is it defaulting to ?

Comment: @R.Bahl: It would default to `10pt` (you will notice a file [`size10.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size10.clo) loaded in your `.log` file). Standard classes offer `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt`. You might be interested in [How to specify font size less than `10pt`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5339/5764) which addresses smaller font sizes in documents.