# Alignment problem in resume

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume

This question uses the suggestions given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63402/altering-the-position-of-bullet-given-by-item). I am formatting my resume for which the following in a basic construct (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,9pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.85}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\hoffset}{3pt}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.6in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7.488in}

\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-3pt} }
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}   {\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{e}}}}\end{minipage}}} \vspace{2pt}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{%
\item \vspace{-.2cm} \textbf{#1} \hfill #2\null\\
#3 \hfill #4%
\vspace{-0.2cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{\LARGE Rohit Bahl}
\end{center}
\begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{3.95in}}l}
My Address Comes Here, Apt \#x& \hfill Phone: 215-xxx-xxxx \\
City, State & \hfill Email: \href{mailto:rbahl@xxxx.edu}{rbahl@xxxx.edu}  \\
\end{tabular*}
\\
\vspace{0.1cm}

\resheading{Education}
\vspace{-.35cm}

\begin{itemize}
\ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}
\begin{itemize}
    \resitem{\textbf{Major}: }
    \resitem{\textbf{Research Focus}}:          
    \resitem{\textbf{Courses}}:         
    \resitem{\textbf{GPA}: x.xx/4.00}
\end{itemize}
    
\ressubheading{Undergrad College }{City}{Bachelor of Technology in Electronics and Communication}{2005 -- 2009}    
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The issue is, although I have tried to align everything on the right side but its always off the mark. As demonstrated in the figure, the credentials and personal information on the right side (city/phone/email/year etc) are not aligning with the title box (Education):[image: example]
What is the best method to do this automatically ? Thanks for your suggestions !

Note: I am modifying the basic template provided by David Grant [here](http://www.davidgrant.ca/latex_resume_template) according to my own preferences.

Comment: Try adding a `@{}` at the end of your `tabular` setup: `\begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{3.95in}}l@{}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an adaptation of what you currently have that aligned things horizontally as you request:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage
\usepackage{color}% http://ctan.org/pkg/color
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.85}

\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-3pt} }
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
  \noindent\fcolorbox{mygrey}{mygrey}{\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule][l]{\textbf{~#1}}}%
}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{%
  \item \textbf{#1} \hfill #2\null\\
  #3 \hfill #4}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{\LARGE Rohit Bahl}
\end{center}
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
  My Address Comes Here, Apt \#x & Phone: 215-xxx-xxxx \\
  City, State & Email: \href{mailto:rbahl@xxxx.edu}{rbahl@xxxx.edu}  \\
\end{tabular*}

\medskip

\resheading{Education}

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \ressubheading{Name of Grad School}{City}{Major}{2010 -- 2012}
  \begin{itemize}
    \resitem{\textbf{Major}: }
    \resitem{\textbf{Research Focus}}:          
    \resitem{\textbf{Courses}}:         
    \resitem{\textbf{GPA}: x.xx/4.00}
  \end{itemize}

  \ressubheading{Undergrad College }{City}{Bachelor of Technology in Electronics and Communication}{2005 -- 2009} 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I've added [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) which can be used to modify list-level separation (vertically). I've used the `nosep` option, which seems to be what you're after - a tight spacing around items and other lists. You would need to peruse the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) in order to modify the settings locally/globally. For example, `topsep=1ex` will give you a top gap of `1ex`.

Also, I've used the following `tabular*` column specification:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
```

This sets the `tabular*` to have width `\textwidth` with 2 columns. The first is `l`eft aligned *without* a preceding column separation space `@{}`, while the second is `r`ight aligned *without* a following column separation space `@{}`. The middle space is stretchable.

You'll notice that I dropped a bunch of your `\vspace` adjustments in lieu of things like `\bigskip` and `\medskip`. This is just a consistency measure since you can modify these things later (if needed). That is, use `\bigskip` whenever you have (say) a separation between distinct/vastly different document elements, while `\medskip` would provide a smaller gap between similarly-styled document elements. Finally, in terms of lengths, it is sometimes better to use font-specific lengths like `em` and/or `ex`, rather than fixed-lengths like `pt`, `mm` and `cm`, since you might want to change the font size later (from the current, non-existent `9pt` to, say, `11pt`). using the former font-specific lengths would then adjust automatically.

Comment: Werner: Thanks for the wonderful explanation ! I will through it step by step to make sure I understand whats going on.

Comment: Werner: I am getting an error while compiling this code. Seems to be a problem with [nosep]:`Package keval Error: nosep undefined`. I installed all the packages being used. Is there something that I am missing ?

Comment: @R.Bahl: Regarding installation of packages and/or updates, it is best to follow the procedure(s) listed in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764) How did you install [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)? Please also include the version number of your current `enumitem` that you obtain from adding `\listfiles` to your preamble and examining the `.log` file. You'll see it near the end *after* `*File List*`. Mine (still under TeX Live 2011) is `2011/09/28 v3.5.2`.

Comment: Werner: I did `sudo fink install enumitem` on a mac, os x 10.5.8. It's showing me version `2009/05/18 v2.2`

Comment: @R.Bahl: Yes, `v3.?` of `enumitem` added a number of new features/options, that `v2.2` does not have. Since I'm not running a Mac and don't know your distribution, I don't know what to tell you in terms of proper installation - I'm running Windows 7. I'm sure someone in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) is running on your operating system and will be able to assist.

Comment: Werner: That's fine. Thanks for ll the info. I am currently updating my distribution and will update the results here once it is completely updated. Thanks again.