# Changing computer modern font size?

Tags: fontsize, computer-modern

Can you change the size of computer modern? In a beamer presentation? And, in the article class, why can't it never go over 12pt?

Comment: Yes. Use `\documentclass[10pt]{article}` or similar. If that doesn't answer your question, please add more information: What documentclass are you using? What font size do you want? Do you want to change the font size for the whole document, or only for certain parts? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You'll need to improve the question a bit for it to be re-opened. The font selection in `beamer` works the same way as in the other document classes. Regarding other font sizes, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt