# How can I set a document font size to 14, 16 or 18 pt?

Tags: fontsize

I usually start with

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
```

but, How can I set a document font size to 14, 16 or 18 pt ?

I had used `{\fontsize{16}{1}    all document }`  and have no desired results.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to specify font size less than 10pt (or more than 12pt)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5339/27635)

Comment: I can´t understand.   an example for 16 pt?

Comment: yes, you can delete, it´s duplicate, I think.

Comment: We can also close it as a duplicate, which will make it easier for others with the same problem to find the question.

Comment: @klingt.net do you want to remove your comment (as it's wrong)

Comment: Sorry but i didn't know that latex article class only has 10 to 12pt as `\documentclass` options. Is there a good for reason for this limitation?

Comment: ok. As you decide.