# Decreasing font size increases border width

Tags: pdftex, fontsize, width

(hopefully) no duplicate of [Number of pages decreases when font size increases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128428/number-of-pages-decreases-when-font-size-increases), because the font size is one of the defaults.

In an attempt to fit more text on a page, I decreased the font size, only to notice that the border size increases.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Huge{Heading}
\end{center}
Text
\end{document}
```

With [11pt], the output is as follows:
[image: 11pt]

With [10pt], the text is of course smaller, but the border is considerably larger:
[image: 10pt]

Does anyone know how this can be prevented, and why it occurs in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the division factor (DIV) to 10 (the default value) to reset the margins (11pt above):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=10]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Huge{Heading}
\end{center}
Text
\end{document}
```

The division factor changes when you change the font size.

Comment: if I do that, my editor answers with a warning: "The detected line width is about x% larger/smaller than the heuristically detected line width" with the remark not to play with DIV. Should I just discard this or could it have somewhat negative consequences?

Comment: @Brokenmind I used the DIV option to explain to you why you are getting a different margin. The DIV is set to 8 when the font size is 10pt while is 10 when the font size is 11pt, so you get a warning when you change its value to something the algorithm considers "bad" for some reason. If you don't like the warning you can use the geometry package to set the margin as you like (result will be the same). You may also want to read the koma manual chapter 2 (specifically from page. 30 on) for an overview of the DIV option and page layout.

Comment: Alright, that also clarifies the warning. I will work through that section, thanks! And somehow, the @-reference doesn't work..