# letter class font size

Tags: fonts, fontsize, letters

How can I increase the base font size to 14pt in standard letter class using xelatex for ease of reading for presbyopic people? which font has better visibility?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Scale` option, but you need to reset the main font; instead of Latin Modern you can use whatever font you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=1.2}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\linespread{1.2}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{R. E. Cipient\\
  Some Place\\
  Some Street}

\opening{Hi,}

this is a letter about getting big type.

\lipsum[1-2]

\closing{Best regards}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why we can't use fontsize=14pt or say 16pts?

Comment: @user34083 Because it is typographically incorrect (and ugly). For some details, see [How to specify font size less than 10pt (or more than 12pt)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt)

Comment: @user34083 The class only supports 10, 11 or 12 points. One could try the `extsizes` package, but with the `Scale` option is surely easier. The only addition is setting `\linespread` to increase the leading.

Comment: Why is it necessary to reset the main font?

Comment: @user1521655 Well, try not doing it and `fontspec` will warn it's not able to do the scaling.