# moderncv with less than 10pt font size

Tags: fontsize, moderncv

I want to make a moderncv resume with font size less than 10pt. I am trying out different font sizes to see which one is best. I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt) question and one comment said that `\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}` worked. How do I combine that line with moderncv? `documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}{moderncv}` or `documentclass[8pt]{moderncv,extarticle}` don't work. Is it possible to achieve this at all?

I even tried adding `\usepackage[fontsize=9pt]{scrextend}` but that throws up errors as well.

Comment: If you tried the basic `extsizes` package? You can use from 8 to 20pt. However I wonder whether someone will want to read a cv in 8 or 9 pt.

Comment: I agree with Bernard that some one may not be happy to read your tiny lettered CV. However, you can use `\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes[11pt]{9pt}` or `\usepackage{anyfontsize}` and \fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont` or `\usepackage[9pt]{extsizes}`. But this all depends upon your font - you should use a scalable font like lmodern, kpfonts etc

Comment: Can either of you make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing an answer from the comments:

- Using the `extsizes` package:

  ```
  \usepackage[9pt]{extsizes}
  ```
- Using the `scrextend` package:

  ```
  \usepackage{scrextend}
  \changefontsizes[11pt]{9pt}
  ```
- Using the `anyfontsize` package:

  ```
  \usepackage{anyfontsize}
  \fontsize{9}{11}
  \selectfont
  ```

Also, use a scalable modern font which scales well to lower font sizes (eg: lmodern, kpfonts). However, in general, it is not recommended to not use such small font sizes in the interest of readability.