# Can the make the font even smaller than 10pt?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I'm using "\documentclass[10pt]{article}" while preparing a document. Can the make the font even smaller? Does decreasing the font size from 12pt to 10pt reduce the size (in kB) of output pdf file?

Comment: By *size*, do you mean the file size (in kB), or the number of pages?

Comment: You can find basic information about fonts on [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts) and some information about small font sizes in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt).

Comment: The set of available font choices is determined by the document class. Are you free to employ a document class other than `article`?