# Changing size in an article document (for hand notes)?

Tags: fontsize

I have herewith a document which is destined to hand notes. It allows to have printed notes on a small sized document. However the size is relatively too small. Since article has not that much options for size changing, which best possibilities might be given to increase sufficiently the size of the whole document for a better readability?

Thank you, With best regards. I wish you a good day!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
\usepackage[textwidth=8cm,textheight=13cm]{geometry} 
\titlespacing{\section}{0.2cm}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\leftskip=1.5em
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\sloppy
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{microtype}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
Hello World 

\section{Section 2}
Hello World 

Bye
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by “too small”.  How much larger should the font size be?

Comment: Maybe `\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}` ?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memoir` class provides options for fontsizes ranging from 9pt to 60pt, but for sizes above 17-20pt the `extrafontsizes` option should be used. `memoir` caters for `article`, `report` and `book` documents; for `article` type documents the `article` option is required whereby chapters are treated as sections, sections as subsections and so on (many people have asked how to change an `article` layout to `report`, or vice-versa). An example:

```
\documentclasss[...,17pt,extrafrontsizes,article]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\chapter[First}% printed as an article's \section{First}
text
\section{Sec}% printed as an article's \subsection
etc
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

One easy option is use the alternative document classes of the [extsizes](https://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) package, that allow default fonts of 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, and 20pt, so you can use for instance:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello} 
Hello, World 
\end{document}
```

Another is the [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=20pt]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello} 
Hello, World 
\end{document}
```

Or use the `scrextend` package, that is part of the Koma-script bundle, with the standard classes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=20pt]{scrextend}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello} 
Hello, World 
\changefontsizes{14pt}
\section{Hello} 
Hello, World 
\end{document}
```

But with this font size LaTeX probably will have troubles for finding good line breaks in several places, no matter that approach is followed. Probably 14pt will be the best compromise between increased readability and reasonable layout.