# Large-Print Version of Exam

Tags: fontsize, exam, resize

I have a student with a visual impairment who needs a large-print version of the upcoming exam.  This involves not only a larger font size but a total rescaling of the whole thing, including diagrams.  Naturally a consequence of this is that the pagination will need to be completely redone (the exam is supposed to be on normal-sized paper).  What is the simplest way to do this?  (Best-case scenario would be a package with a command like `\begin{large-print}` that takes care of everything automatically but that seems unlikely.)

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30699/ can be useful, or otherwise some redefinitions on the preamble to change `\footnotesize` into `\normalsize`, `\normalsize` into `\Large`, etc.

Comment: IMHO I'd let the printerdriver handle this. E.g.: in adobe-PDF viewer you can set the scale to 200% and check "posterprint" Other PDF viewer may be able to do the same...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle -- the question clearly says that the exam is supposed to be on normal-sized paper.  that could be for one of several reasons: for ease of handling the completed exams when collected; so that the page size is not inconvenient on the available work area; so that the student is not singled out as being obviously "different"; .... a reasonable requirement, though one that does add a number of complications.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to redo everything and have the ability to print on double page paper (A3 in Europe), you can enlarge the whole pages with the command :

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a3paper]
```

In the opposite case, or if you should keep the " normal-sized paper" you can have a try on the [`extsizes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) package which allows to write:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,17pt]{extarticle}
```

For the figures, it is more intricate, because it depends on their format, size and aspect ratio.

Comment: Note that `extsize` does not support the `exam` class (although it is not clear whether @mweiss uses that).

Comment: @Marjin. I agree, it is not clear. As a teacher,  I never use this class or package but my own defined class based on ``article``, which also works with ``extsize`` package.