# Create two documents with different page sizes

Tags: automation, paper-size, arara

I need to create two versions of a pdf rendered from my .tex file, one in A4 one-side format, and one in B5 two-side format.

I do this by changing the class options (I use memoir, if that matters) and re-rendering the file. Is there any better way?

Comment: You can change the page size using geometry, but the `\if@twoside` flag should be set using the document class.

Comment: So I can do it only once and there’s no way to use one .tex file to generate two documents without manually changing that between renders?

Comment: It is one pdf per run anyway.  TeX was written back when RAM was expensive.

Comment: Sure. I hoped things have changed with XeTeX (or maybe LuaTeX), but if not, it’s not that big of a deal. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I often create booklets in standard and large-print formats in different sizes from a single source. There are a few approaches.

If there is certain content that needs to be included or excluded from different formats, you could use something like the [`comment`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) or [`multiaudience`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience) packages.

## Passing arguments to a single file

If you want a single file from which to generate multiple formats, you could use something like this `text.tex`, with optional setup for [`arara`](https://ctan.org/pkg/arara):

```latex
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex: { options: ['--jobname=text-largeprint', '\def\largeprint{}\input{text}'] }

\documentclass{scrbook}

\ifdefined\largeprint
  \KOMAoptions{paper=A4, oneside, fontsize=16pt, DIV=calc}
\else
  \KOMAoptions{paper=B5, twoside, fontsize=10pt, DIV=calc}
\fi

\begin{document}
  Text
\end{document}
```

The B5 version would run normally with `lualatex text.tex`. To produce the A4 version in a separate file called `text-largeprint.pdf`:

```sh
$ lualatex --jobname=text-largeprint "\def\largeprint{}\input{text}"
```

If you include the comments at the beginning of the file, you can then run both commands at once:

```sh
$ arara text.tex
```

## Using `latexmk` with multiple files

You could also create two files with the options you want and another with the source text, then run `latexmk` to generate both versions at once. This is one way to organize the files:

1. `a4.tex`

```latex
\documentclass[paper=A4, oneside, fontsize=16pt, DIV=calc]{scrbook}

\input{text}
```

2. `b5.tex`

```latex
\documentclass[paper=B5, twoside, fontsize=10pt, DIV=calc]{scrbook}

\input{text}
```

3. `text.tex`

```latex
\begin{document}
  Text
\end{document}
```

4. `latexmkrc` (tells `latexmk` which files to compile)

```
@default_files = ('a4.tex', 'b5.tex');
```

## `pgfpages` package

If the pagination needs to be the same, it's much easier to resize the PDF to another size, although the design might look a bit off: this has already been covered in [Large-print version of exam](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440059/large-print-version-of-exam).