# How to use natbib package and fancyhdr package together

Tags: header-footer, natbib, fancyhdr, footer, fancy

Please how can I get to use fancyhdr package with natbib package. It happens that I can't use the two in my document, what can be wrong? and how can I correct that, please?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{} % This clears whatever was there before
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Set to 0 if you don't want a bar at the bottom.
\fancyhead[RE, RO]{\thepage} % Right even, right odd pages.
\fancyhead[LE, LO]{\textsc \rightmark} % Right even, right odd pages.
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Set to 0 if you don't want a bar at the bottom.
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\begin{large}

%\begin{figure}
    %\centering
%\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{UI.jpg}
%\end{figure}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\Large{\textsc{By}} \\


\vfill




\Large{\sc{A project in the department of mathematics, submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the award of bachelor of science (mathematics), \\ }}
\vfill
\Large{\textsc{April, 2023.}}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{\center \Huge \textbf{CERTIFICATION}}
We certify that this project was carried out by \textbf{}, in the Department of Mathematics, Faculty of Science,, under my supervision.

\vspace{5cm}

\begin{center}
\line(1,0){180}
\hspace{10cm}
(Supervisor)\\

\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Certification}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
Ordinary differential equations (ODEs) are commonly employed to represent the behavior of dynamic systems in various fields of science and engineering. However, ODEs have certain limitations when it comes to describing dynamics that involve discontinuities, impulses, and uncertain behaviors. Consequently, ordinary differential inclusions (ODIs) have been successfully employed as a useful approach to model such systems.\\

The concept of differential inclusion was studied broadly by Jean-Pierre Aubin, a mathematician from France, during the early 1980s. Differential inclusion is a versatile mathematical tool that extends the scope of differential equations and is utilized to represent diverse phenomena in both physical and social sciences. ODIs have applications in many fields, including control theory, economics, and population dynamics, physics, etc.\\[5pt]
In recent times, ODIs have gained considerable attention, and researchers have increasingly shown interest in exploring the characteristics of the solution set of ODIs, such as their properties of boundedness, uniqueness, and existence.\\[5pt]
The objective of this study is to examine and review the set of solutions for ordinary differential inclusions (ODIs) and establish criteria for the existence of solutions.\\[5pt]
Additionally, we apply our findings to a diverse range of examples in fields such as control theory, economics, and biology.

\citep{Doe:1966}
\citep{key}
\bibliography{MyReferences}
%\bibliography{sample}
\nocite{*}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

\end{large}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide what you believe to be evidence for the claim that one "can't use the two [packages] in my document".

Comment: Can I get your mailing address? I can mail the MWE to you, sir.

Comment: We do not have the file `MyReferences.bib`, so we cannot see, if there is a problem with the bibliography. Please try to extend it to a [minimal working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/277964). As it is, I do not get any error message. However there are several problems with the shown code:

Comment: Note: `\Large` isn't a command with argument but a font switch. So `\Larger{…}` does not make sense, but should be `{\Larger …\par}` …

Comment: Instead of the old font command `\sc`, which is also not a command with argument, but a font switch, you should use `\textsc{…}` or `{\scshape …}` …

Comment: If you use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{…}` it usually should at least immediately after the corresponding `\chapter*`. The later the `\addcontentsline` is placed, the higher the risk that the wrong page will be entered in the table of contents. For a multi-page bibliography, an `\addcontentsline` after `\bibliography` would definitely be too late. In this case, the `tocbibind` package is recommended. …

Comment: Never use `\\ ` or `\\[5pt]` at the end of a paragraph. The do not really add a new paragraph. If you want paragraphs with distance instead of indent of the first line, use package `parskip`.

Comment: The default of `report` is `oneside`. With `oneside` documents all pages are odd pages. So the `RE` and `LE` options of `\fancyhead` do not make any sense.

Comment: How can I then correct that? The thing is, if I can get your mailing address, I can share you everything. So, you can help me debug,

Comment: The `center` environment is a `trivlist` environment that adds extra space. It should not be misused as `\center` environment and never without the corresponding end-command. To locally switch to centering just use `\centering` instead of `\center`. BTW: IMHO adding formatting commands like `\center` or `\Huge` to the argument of a sectioning command could be a hack, but never clean coding.

Comment: You don't need our mailing addresses to show a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/277964). And in most cases, I have briefly explained how to eliminate the other impurities. If you need more help, either have a look into already available questions like: [When to use \par and when \\, \newline, or blank lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664/277964), or ask new questions with appropriate minimal working examples.

Comment: `\chapter*{…}` by default already uses `\bfseries`, so no need to use `\textbf{…}` in the argument. And with `report` using `\Huge` for chapters is also a default. So no need to use `\Huge` inside the argument of `\chapter*{…}`.

Comment: Using `\begin{large}…\end{large}` is not good style, because `\large` is a font switch, that should not be misused as an environment. Using `\begin{large}…\end{large}` to try to increase the font size of the whole document is at least ugly. If you really need a larger document font than 12pt please read: [How to specify font size less than 10pt (or more than 12pt)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5339/277964)

Comment: I think your assumption that the unnamed problem with your document is the simultaneous use of the packages `fancyhdr` and `natbib` is not correct. You should therefore explicitly name the actual problem and make it reproducible for us with a suitable MWE or, if necessary, MWEB. Otherwise your question stays unclear and the only thing (beside the impurities listed above) I can guess would be, that option `twoside` is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Your presumption, that you cannot use packages `fancyhdr` and `natbib` together is surely wrong. A lot of documents are using both packages, for example:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{pkg:fancyhdr,
  author={Pieter van Ostrum},
  title={{\textsc{fancyhdr}}---Extensive control of page headers and footers in {\LaTeXe}},
  year=2022,
  note={\url={https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr}},
}
@misc{pkg:natbib,
  author={Patrick W. Daly},
  title={{\textsc{natbib}}---Flexible bibliography support},
  year=1993,
  note={\url{https://ctan.org/pkg/natbib}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}% bibliography entry (an others) to the ToC
%\usepackage{parskip}% Try this, if you want paragraph distance instead of first line indent.

\usepackage{mwe}% Useful for dummy text in minimal working examples.

\fancyhead[RE]{\scshape\nouppercase \leftmark}% makes sense only with class option twoside
\fancyhead[LO]{\scshape\nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}% LE makes sense only with class option twoside
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}% simply an author-year-style but without any relation to APA

\begin{document}
\title{Demonstration of Package Combination}
\author{Cabohah}
\date{2024-01-13}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Using packages \textsc{natbib} and \textsc{fancyhdr} together}
There isn't a real problem in using packages \textsc{natbib}
\citep{pkg:natbib} and \textsc{fancydr} \citep{pkg:fancyhdr} together. Indeed
these packages are independent and usually do not influence each other.

\section{Only a demonstration section}
\lipsum[1-5]

\bibliography{\jobname}

\clearpage
If there would be additional entries in the bibliography, so that it would
need more than one page, you would get the same page header on even
bibliography pages like on this page.
\clearpage
If there would be additional entries in the bibliography, so that it would
need more than two pages, you would get the same page header on odd
bibliography pages like on this page.

\end{document}
```

[image: title page]

[image: pages 2&3]

[image: pages 4&5]

[image: pages 6&7]

So I guess your problem is not the combination of these packages but another one. But unfortunately your question does neither tell us the problem nor the expected result. I therefore have little hope that this answer will tell you more than that your basic assumption that the two packages are incompatible is not correct.