How can I check my font size?
I need to check what font size a template I've downloaded has incorporated. I'm working with luateX and I need my text to be specifically 14pt, so it can't be just one of the normal ones (small, medium, large etc.). The point is that this template has already some text in it, which I need to keep, so I cannot just cancel everything and select my preferred pts from scratch. Is there a quick and simple way to do this? Here's the template, hoping to provide all the needed informations. Just one more thing: I need to specifically know the pts for the main text as well as the ones of \sections, \subsections and index. Thanks in advance.
\documentclass[a4paper,10 pt,titlepage,oneside]{book}


\usepackage[luatex]{color, graphicx}


\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array,epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{emptypage}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand*\contentsname{Indice}}
\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand*\refname{Bibliografia}}

\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\CP}{\mathbb{CP}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\LC}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\support}{\mathrm{support}}
\newcommand{\Oset}{\varnothing}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
%per gli spazi:
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing

\providecommand\phantomsection{}




%\usepackage{stmaryrd} 






%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
%style=alphabetic,
%sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{Lit.bib}

\setlength\parindent{24pt}


\newcommand{\bigzero}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 0}}
\newcommand{\rvline}{\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}\vline\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\newcommand{\heart}{\gamma}
\renewcommand\epsilon{\varepsilon}
\renewcommand\phi{\varphi}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\TimesNewRomanFont[
Scale=1,Ligatures={TeX},
BoldFont={TimesNewRoman Bold}, 
ItalicFont={TimesNewRoman Italic},
]{TimesNewRoman}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[abspage]{zref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\saveabspage[1]{\zref@labelbyprops{#1}{abspage}}
\newcommand*\getabspage[1]{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{abspage}{-1}}
\makeatother

\addto\captionsitalian{%
  \renewcommand{\bibname}
    {Bibliografia}}

\begin{document}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\linespread{1.5}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begingroup


You template uses option 10 pt (which should be 10pt). So the basic font size is 10pt. If you need 14pt instead → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt

BTW: You should reduce your preamble to what is really needed for your document. Note also, that you should not use package fontenc or  lmodern with LuaLaTeX. Loading packages more than once also makes no sense.

Never do \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} in lualatex it would completely break the unicode support, fortunately here you load fontspec later which corrects this and restores Unicode encoding. No document written after 1994 should be using epsfig are you really using that?

The \fontsize command sets both the font size and \baselineskip, and advises to make \baselineskip 1.2 times the font size.  So \the\dimexpr \baselinskip/1.2\relax sort of works.  Actually, 12pt font has \baselineskip=14.5pt.
